# Visual force page slowness for first time access and second time access is OK

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

Requistion object is part of "Strategic Accounts" application in URL https://my.salesforce.com.
It is part of instance NA23 instance.

Requestions is tab. Access any requestion object/webapge using Requestions Tab and click the "Questionanaire" button. This page pop up Visual force page.
Here user is waiting for 30 to 60 minutes or web page timed out to display question contents. It is observed for EST timezone users. Means 1 AM to 7 AM PST timings. Users also reporting that first time in the day they observed this 
behaviour and second time or later clicking that button working normally. we did not see any heavy back up process or any system activity at that time. So we want your help to figure out why this slowness is happening in salesforce.

steps to produce: 1) login into https://my.salesforce.com 2) select app Strategic Accounts application 3) select any Requestion ( probably with status "Awaiting branch Submission") 4) click "View Questionaire" button 5) Here users observing slow ness

Comment: you should refer to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213798&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%2F&type=1 for troubleshooting network issues

Comment: If the page is data/soql intensive the first person to access it for the day will experience slowness while SF rebuild caches / indexes that have become invalid. Also - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25334/why-is-my-soql-query-slow-the-first-time-faster-subsequently

Comment: Have you tried the various solutions from the doc on optimizing Visualforce performance?  There are a lot of tools to help understand the cause like the query optimizer, etc.  See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_visualforce_best_practices.meta/salesforce_visualforce_best_practices/pages_best_practices_perf_optimizations.htm